# How to deploy an heroku application and ignore a file?

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

I am building a web application for an online "build your own" card game. In the application, I have a `cards.json` file that holds custom card data. This file is changed with fs whenever a user creates a card. 
Whenever I push local changes, the `cards.json` file gets overwritten on deploy. That means all the remote data gets lost on every deploy. How can I include a `cards.json` file remotely but not change the file whenever I push changes using `git push heroku master`?
EDIT: I guess for clarification reasons, I have tried using a `.gitignore` as well as removing the file from the staging area. I'm not entirely sure, but I think the issue is that when the application is deployed the file is overwritten there.

Answer (score 1):

So I just found out that the data created during runtime will always be deleted/reset.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem

I guess the best fixes for anyone else who has this same issue are:

a) Look into Databases and Heroku Add-ons, or

b) This is very workaround, and there might be better ways to do it, but:

```
// Go into a new directory, and use
$ heroku ps:copy <FILENAME> --app <APPNAME>
// Then, copy+paste the data from this file into your main repo.
/* Now, each time you do this, you need to make sure you delete that file from the 
 * extra directory you created as ps:copy only works when the file doesnt exist locally.
 */
```

I think `git fetch` doesn't work in this instance, as it only pulls that unchanged file, rather than the changed one from the dyno.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the .gitignore file in git, seems to me that's exactly what you're looking for.

If it doesn't recognize .gitignore properly at first:

```
git add [uncommitted changes you want to keep] && git commit
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "fixed untracked files"
```

Comment: I have tried to use .gitignore for this, and it didnt seem to work for me. I do want a remote copy of `cards.json`, and even when I do ignore changes to the file, it still is overwritten on deploy.

Comment: Then something it probably not configured right. Can you provide more information on what exactly you did? Overall, if it's written correctly, there's no reason it shouldn't work.

Comment: @Malmadork by the way, you can try doing what I edited in my answer if it doesn't recognize .gitignore properly at first

Comment: Basically, when I try removing all the cache, update `.gitignore`, and push changes, it crashes because the file does not exist when I use `require('cards.json')`. I guess all the things I have tried include: changing gitignore, `git rm -r --cached .` then updating gitignore, `git rm --cached cards.json`, `git update-index --skip-worktree cards.json`, `git reset cards.json`, `git checkout cards.json`... these didnt seem to work.

Comment: I did just try to double check and see if your answer worked, and it didnt. What I've been testing to make sure it works is: adding data to `cards.json` on the application, then `git add . && git commit -m "Fixed untracked files && git push heroku master`. Then upon rerunning the application, I can see that the `cards.json` file gets overwritten. I can see this as the data entered before pushing local changes no longer exists.

Comment: @Malmadork what you should do is do the steps of the gitignore I wrote above, and then log in to the server and create the cards.json file there. This way, it wouldn't be tracked and it would still exist on the remote server.

Answer (score -2):

In .gitignore add the cards.json along with the path .
eg. src/test/resources/testdata/cards.json